# XMarks for Chrome not working

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, xmarks

For some reason, XMarks never completes synchronizing... It just gets stuck. I've tried "Changing Profiles" and it says I've got the wrong password or something similar. (Normal sign-in with https://login.xmarks.com/ works, though.)

Anyone else having the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's fixed... for now.

I signed out, logged in again, `Settings->Advanced->Download Bookmarks`, resynchronized, and now it seems to be working (for now).